# How to write Swift in Google Colabs?

Tags: swift, google-colaboratory

I've seen that Colabs supports Swift now. However, I always get the same message whenever I try to run the most basic Swift code; even from available online examples.

As soon as I open one of this notebooks, I am greeted with this message:

Unrecognized runtime "swift"; defaulting to "python3"

Every Swift code that I try to run defaults to a syntax error. I hope someone here can help me. Thanks.

PS: I don't know if its of any use... but I am using a windows laptop and mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Swift for TensorFlow [was cancelled](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26117453) in early 2021. It's no longer supported.

Comment: In particular, the Swift runtime for Colab was wound down soon after that public announcement. The [Swift Jupyter kernel](https://github.com/google/swift-jupyter) that was used in Colab is still available, if you wish to run your own Swift Jupyter notebooks. (Disclaimer: I'm a former member of the Swift for TensorFlow team.)